# How to get activity log of release manager in Play Console?

Tags: android, google-play-console

I have an issue with activity log on play console. Our company previous release manger log is showing on activity log but other release manger log not showing.

In item column show "Device catalog Terms of Service accepted".
In Changes column show "Accept".

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your question. Could you perhaps explain it a bit more clearly. Another option would be to contact Google Play Console support, who can see all the details of your account to help you. You can contact them via the "Help" menu in the Play console, which is accessed by clicking the "?" question mark icon.

Comment: @NickFortescue thanks